# Customizing XStream output

Tags: xml, collections, xml-serialization, converters, xstream

I have a class that resembles something like this:

```
class foo {
    List<String> bar;
    ...
}
```

I add four Strings to the list `bar`:

```
bar.add("1");
bar.add("2");
bar.add("3");
bar.add("4");
```

Using xstream, I've managed to get output that looks like this:

```
<foo>
  <bar>
     <blah>1</blah>
     <blah>2</blah>
     <blah>3</blah>
     <blah>4</blah>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

However, I need XML that looks like this:

```
<foo>
  <bar>
     <blah id="1"/>
     <blah id="2"/>
     <blah id="3"/>
     <blah id="4"/>
     ...
  </bar>
</foo>
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the output you want by doing the following:

1: Create the Blah class, unless you want all Strings to behave show as attributes.

```
@XStreamAlias("blah")
public class Blah {
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    String id;

    Blah(){};

    Blah(String s) {
    this.id = s;
    }
}
```

2: Your foo has a collection of blahs

```
@XStreamAlias("foo")
public class Foo {
    List<Blah> bar = new ArrayList<Blah>();
}
```

3: Tell XStream to process the annotations

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.processAnnotations(Foo.class);
xstream.processAnnotations(Blah.class);
System.out.println(xstream.toXML(f));
```

4: That's the output:

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    <blah id="1"/>
    <blah id="2"/>
    <blah id="3"/>
    <blah id="4"/>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me this way of processing xstream. I wasn't aware of its support for annotations. I'll try this way out too.

Answer (score 0):

In case this isn't supported by XStream, it can be done using [MOXy JAXB](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php).  You will need to use the @XmlPath annotation:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Foo {
    @XmlPath("bar/blah/@id")
    List<String> bar; 
}
```

You can produce the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
   <bar>
      <blah id="1"/>
      <blah id="2"/>
      <blah id="3"/>
      <blah id="4"/>
   </bar>
</foo>
```

With this demo code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.bar = new ArrayList<String>();
        foo.bar.add("1"); 
        foo.bar.add("2"); 
        foo.bar.add("3"); 
        foo.bar.add("4"); 

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }
}
```

For more information see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did manage to get my desired output with the XStream `CollectionConverter`.